# Contar o Cuenta en un SELECT MySQL

Tags: mysql

quisiera hacer una consulta con un columna que me enumere los resultados pero hasta cierto punto y luego reiniciar la cuenta: Por ejemplo:

La consulta me enumera mis 8 resultados.. en este caso nombre.

1. Carolina
2. Claudia
3. Daniel
4. Francisco
5. Jose
6. Maria
7. Mirta
8. Romina

Pero lo que yo quiero es que cuente 4 registro y vuelva a empezar. Ejemplo:

1. Carolina
2. Claudia
3. Daniel
4. Francisco

y ahí reiniciamos...

1. Jose
2. Maria
3. Mirta
4. Romina

Se podra???

Yo lo pensaba así, para enumerarlas todas, pero no se como parar en 4 y empezar de nuevo en la misma consulta.

```
SELECT apellido,nombre, CAST(@s:=@s+1 AS UNSIGNED) AS '#' 
FROM mitabla,
(SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
WHERE   ciudad = "NEUQUEN" and ORDER BY apellido asc, nombre asc
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Contanos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Por favor presta atención al comentario anterior y describe cual es el criterio por el cual quieres reiniciar el contador: ¿Cada 4? ¿Cuando cambia un grupo?

Comment: Claro... quiero cada 4...  y no tengo idea como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente haces "módulo 4" del resultado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo has resuelto:

```
SELECT apellido,
       nombre, 
       CAST(@s:= (CASE WHEN @s = 4 THEN 1 ELSE @s+1 END) AS UNSIGNED) AS '#' 
       FROM mitabla,
       (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
       WHERE   ciudad = "NEUQUEN" 
       ORDER BY apellido asc, nombre asc
```

Con `(CASE WHEN @s = 4 THEN 1 ELSE @s+1 END)` reiniciamos el contador cada vez que llegamos a 4.

Comment: GRACIASSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!