# Contar o Cuenta y agregar en un SELECT MySQL

Tags: sql

hace unos dias me solucionaron un problemon para enumerar un resultado de consulta pero parar el contador y volver a empezarlo en la misma consulta...

[Contar o Cuenta en un SELECT MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207168/contar-o-cuenta-en-un-select-mysql?noredirect=1#comment386914_207168)

de echo yo queria llegar a este resultado ( parando en 4 )

1. Carolina
2. Claudia
3. Daniel
4. Francisco

y ahí reiniciamos...

1. Jose
2. Maria
3. Mirta
4. Romina

Ese tema.. SOLUCIONADO! ahora en realidad queria grabar en otra columna temporal un identificado de cada secuencia o enumeracion...

1. Carolina .1
2. Claudia .1
3. Daniel .1
4. Francisco .1

y ahí reiniciamos... y empieza el segundo ciclo

1. Jose .2
2. Maria .2
3. Mirta .2
4. Romina .2

y asi sucesivante.... se podra?? Espero puedan ayudarme como lo hicieron anteriormente..

Comment: Pero, si ya lograste esto y devuelve una tabla con los numeros, que impide que guardes esa tabla como nueva? si no, donde los querrias guardar?

Comment: Necesito contar los ciclos digamos... fíjate detrás de los nombres...

Comment: mmm.. y si sabes el primer numero, no podes usar la misma logica.. o sea.. cuando llegas a 4, incrementas esta segunda variable, y reseteas la primera? igual todo esto, para una base de datos, suena muy raro...

Comment: me esta partiendo la cabeza... disculpen! estoy aprendiendo mucho!

Comment: Si esta perfecto. Pero cual es la finalidad de que la base de datos haga estas cosas? igual se entiende lo que te propongo hacer? no lo pongo como respuesta, porque es lo mismo que antes...

Comment: Si, te entiendo... pero creo q mi problema es mas como poder jugar con CAST... para comparar dentro de una consulta... (va, creo)

Comment: jajaja Lo siento pero me esta quemando el cerebro!! debe ser una pavada para ustedes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la respuesta anterior, Patricio te hizo hacer un producto cartesiano entre 2 tablas, una con tus datos, y otra con una columna en 0, para que pudieras ir iterando sobre la misma e ir contando resultados.

Si nos robamos su idea, podemos agregar otra columna mas.. y esta reiniciarla solo cuando la primera pase 4... algo asi:

```
SELECT apellido,
   nombre, 
   CAST(@s:= (CASE WHEN @s = 4 THEN 1 ELSE @s+1 END) AS UNSIGNED) AS '#',
   CAST(@t:= (CASE WHEN @s = 4 THEN @t+1 ELSE @t END) AS UNSIGNED) AS 't#'
   FROM mitabla,
   (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s,
   (SELECT @t:= 0) AS t
   WHERE   ciudad = "NEUQUEN" 
   ORDER BY apellido asc, nombre asc
```

Si la idea es correcta, esto sumaria a t, cada vez que s llegue a 4...

Comment: GROSOOO q vergüenza me da! me siento un burroooo...

Comment: el tema que cambia en 4... y tendría q cambiar en 1 del proximo ciclo...

Comment: Entonces cambia el 4 por un 1. Para que cambie ahi.

Comment: SON LOS MAS.... reitero q me siento un burroooo! Gracias Muchachos!

Comment: gbianchi CRACK!